# How to parse this JSON in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, json

**JSON data :**

```
  {
      "response": {
      "latitude": {
         "1": "28.5700",
         "2": "28.5700"
      },
      "longitude": {
         "1": "77.329999",
         "2": "77.3200"
      },
      "gps_location_look_up": {
         "1": "1",
         "2": "1"
      }

   }
}
```

How can one parse this json data and get these values (latitude,longitude) **using JavaScript**? How can one retrieve value of other keys?

Comment: First of all it is not valid json copy and pate here jsonlint.com and check

Comment: it is a valid json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing json has nothing to do with phone gap/cordova; its pure javascript: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/535275)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('{\
    "response": {\
       "latitude": {\
          "1": "28.5700",\
          "2": "28.5700"\
       },\
       "longitude": {\
          "1": "77.329999",\
          "2": "77.3200"\
       },\
       "gps_location_look_up": {\
          "1": "1",\
          "2": "1"\
       }\
    }\   
}');
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect. You have to pass `.parse()` a string, not an object. Should be `JSON.parse('{...}');` and also be 1 line then because string literals can't span lines in JavaScript.